# Custom ProgressBar Indeterminate

Tags: angular, progress-bar, angular5, primeng

I use primng in my angular project. Is it possible customising the [ProgressBar Indeterminate](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/progressbar) ? I would like replace ligne by three point ?

Or, do you have other ideas ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use something like [that](https://codepen.io/bobanko/pen/yqtvh) ?

Comment: thank you ! Sorry, I'm not find in research google.

Comment: It less, it not scss. ".circle()" compiled error :(

Comment: Here is a scss example : https://codepen.io/FabioG/pen/EKLMPb

Comment: Thank you very much. For info, I find SCSS -> https://nzbin.github.io/three-dots/ very simple to implementation in my Angular project :-)